# Загрузка файла на сайт средствами Python + Selenium + PyWinAuto

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pywinauto

Всем доброго дня! В данный момент пытаюсь автоматизировать загрузку документов на сайт. Процедура стандартная: переходим на сайт, там переходим в нужный раздел, где выбираем добавить файл, открывается стандартный "обзорщик" в котором мы можем найти файл и загрузить его. 
Использую PyWinAuto для работы с окном, но успехов нет.

```
try:
    pwa_app = pywinauto.application.Application()
    wind = pwa_app.window(title='Открытие').window(class_name='Edit').Edit.type_keys("pywinauto Works!")
except:
    print("Don't Ok")
```

Само по себе окно он видит, пробовал выводить по нему инфу, но вот не хочет, например, изменять строку поиска файла, для перехода в нужную папку. Для обнаружения элементов окна использую AutoIt Window Info.
Если у кого-то был опыт работы, прошу подсказать, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решена следующий способом:

```
    app = pywinauto.application.Application()
    app.connect(title='Открытие')
    app.Dialog.Edit0.TypeKeys(r'C:\Users\Name\Documents\Flash\upload_docs\фото.jpg', with_spaces=False)
    app.Dialog.Edit0.TypeKeys('{ENTER}')
```

Код находит окно выбора файла (title='Открытие'), далее в поле "Имя файла" (app.Dialog.**Edit0**.TypeKeys) вводит адрес и нажимает Enter.